# Sync files between Mac and raspberry pi

Tags: macos, file-sharing

I want to be able to access a folder (offline) with all my web stuff in there. Then when I get a connection to the Raspberry Pi, I want it to sync from my mac to the pi. Basically, I want to be able to work offline and be able to upload my file to the Apache web server, in /var/www. FileZilla using sFTP doesn't work, loads of file transfer errors (i have permission to edit the files without sudo in ssh).

Comment: Unless you are more specific you will not get any answers.

Comment: If you're getting file transfer errors, I'm doubting your permissions are actually set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to this by setting up a [local git server](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server) on your pi.

Git is a version control system that is built around a branch-merge control system. This basically means that when you're working on a feature for your project you edit a local 'branch' of the repository, which stored on your device. This local branch is essentially a copy of the master branch which is on the git server. When you're done, you can 'merge' your local branch into the master branch.

This makes git a popular choice for repository management for a couple of reasons:

- Because you are working on branches, you can easily revert your code back to what is on the master branch.
- Many people can work on multiple branches which git can *magically* merge back into the master branch.
- Version control means you can revert to any previous point in the repository.

For more information you can visit git's website [here](https://git-scm.com/)

Comment: Camp Bell, I originally converted your answer to a comment based on your text, but then I realized that this is honestly a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: If you wanted to improve your answer, it would be better to expand as to why you think using Git would work here.

Comment: Jacobm001 I tried and realised I couldn't do it. Just saying it's a version control system doesn't really seem to cut it.

Comment: I'm sure you could write a good answer. It may not be perfect on your first try, but that's what comments and edits are for. Just the fact that you knew to suggest git is a good start. But what about git's tool chain helps here? What are the broad strokes of how this kind of workflow works? You don't need to detail every little bit here, just give the highlights.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it's sufficient

Answer (score 1):

export the directory on the pi with nfs and then use rsync to synchronize the files from the mac to the pi or vice versa.